# Reading list on rewriting systems?

Tags: lo.logic, big-list, type-theory, lambda-calculus, term-rewriting-systems

I am new to studying rewriting systems as a first year PhD student.  I would like to propose a special topics course on rewriting theory, and I want to make sure I don't leave any of the original sources out.

I have a copy of Barendregt and Terese as textbook sources.  For original paper's: I have been looking at Dershowitz's work on proving termination, Huet's paper on confluence, Van Oostrom's paper on decreasing diagrams, and Ohlebusch's paper on confluence modulo equivalence, and Toyama's work on modularity.  I hope to end up with a smattering of both classical and recent influential papers.  Also, if anyone can recommend some good papers on the links between algebraic topology, category theory, and rewriting theory, I would appreciate that as well.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't have a specific recommendation for your reading list, but I want to alert you to the excellent survey on "Rewrite Systems" by Dershowitz and Jouannaud in Handbook of Theoretical Computer Science, volume B.